# css: why has <input> effect on parent div's width

Tags: html, css

Consider the following HTML

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="img.jpg"/>
    <div class="bc">
        <input type="file"/>
        <button>Upload</button>    
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
    margin-left: 10% ;
    margin-right: 10% ;
    height: 100px ;
    background-color: lightgrey ;
}
img {
    height: 100% ;
}

.bc {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: grey ;
    vertical-align:middle
}
input {
    visibility: hidden ;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    display:inline;
}
```

When I remove the 'input' element, the width of 'bc' is more or less equal to the button, but when it precent, 'bc' gets huge (in width). [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/Bfkpx/) is my jsfiddle. Can someone explain why this is and how I can undo that effect (because I need the input field there)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Added width to your input element in CSS and it works fine.

```
 input {
        visibility: hidden ;
        width: 50px;
        display:inline;
    }
```

Comment: that is weird. If I set it to a width of 1px, I have the result I want. What happens there if I set it to 0 ?

Comment: You can't take width as 0px.

then will show the same result as its showing now in your fiddle.

Comment: I know that 0 === 0px, but why is there such a huge difference between 0 and 1px?

Comment: When you set its width to 0,it occupies its default space of 238px in your div.

Answer (score 6):

```
visibility: hidden;
```

makes your element invisible, but it is "still there",

```
display:none;
```

gets rid of it from the flow of elements, and it won't affect any other elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can use css to remove the  field by setting *display: none;*. This will fix the problem.

```
input {
   display: none;
}
```